# After installing the OS(both in general and especially Ubuntu/any Linux) , Do we need to install root certificates separately?

Tags: virtualbox, ssl, https

[image]

I have installed ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso in Oracle VM VirtualBox. The details are above. I have tried both Minimal Installation and Normal Instalation type while installing Ubuntu. The following problem is in both instances.

When I tried to open Google.com earlier in firefox,  I got error code `sec_error_unknown_issuer` on clicking advanced button. There is no button **accept the risk and continue**

After few minutes I was working in Host OS(windows 10) I tried again now I got error code as `MOZZILA_PKIX_ERROR_MITM_DETECTED` with **accept the risk and continue** button. I can't understand what changed the error code and made the accept and continue option available.

Also I tried from earlier to install postman from terminal by this comman

```
sudo snap install postman
```

It's always failing

```
error: cannot install "postman": Post
       https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

In `/usr/share/ca-certificates` directory there is only one directory name `mozilla`

After researching about certificate authority, I guess I may need to install a root certificate. But I got my question now, "Won't Ubuntu installation take care of installing root certificate ?"

Do we need to install root certificate after installing OS (windows, Mac or any OS) ?

Comment: Try changing your DNS.

Comment: Ubuntu will happily install certificates with the rest of the normal desktop install...but you chose a Minimal install. So installing those certificates is up to you.

Comment: @user535733 I have installed another VM instance with same iso. This time it is Normal installation not minimal one. the same problem exists in the normal installation also.

Comment: How strange. I happened to do a test install of Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop in a VM yesterday for unrelated reasons...and the browser works perfectly - no certificate errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, users don't need to install any certificates separately to access websites like google.com or Bing.com

This certificate issues were solved by disabling [BC Unified Agent](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135378/what-does-blue-coat-unified-agent-application-do)