# Certificate error in Ubuntu 20.04 vm using VirtualBox

Tags: 20.04

I have installed ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso in Oracle VM VirtualBox. But there are certificate issues . I cannot access any https (e.g. https://www.google.com) using Firefox or Chrome. Similarly curl gives issue.
I want to install Kubernetes in this vm. But it is reporting similar error with those distribution sites.
I tried installing, and reinstallaing ca-certiicates. It still not working.

This post indicates that BC Unified Agent needs to be disabled. I am unsure how to do that.
[After installing the OS(both in general and especially Ubuntu/any Linux) , Do we need to install root certificates separately?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258697/after-installing-the-osboth-in-general-and-especially-ubuntu-any-linux-do-we/1387212#1387212)

Thanks in advance for any help/pointer.

[Screenshot 1: Virtualbox vm setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a5Ru.jpg)

[Screenshot 2: browser and curl reports certificate issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNAQx.jpg)

Comment: Check System date time and timezone in Ubuntu. Provide Proper time and timezone and then try to browse https site. If you have wrong time in your system you will get Untrusted connection error while connecting to site that uses ssl.

Comment: @JohanPalych I tried with date timezone as well. But it didn't helped. I am connected with VPN. of same location

Comment: Did you got any solutions ?

Comment: On which host is virtualbox, Windows, Linux installed?

Comment: Hi, I was trying it on Windows 10

Comment: I'm sorry. These are the problems of configuring Virtualbox on Windows. This forum is for configuring Virtualbox on Ubuntu.
Theoretically, a conflict is possible with: Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform, Container, Windows Defender Application Protection

Answer (score 3):

[image]Go to virtual box and select your ubuntu os and go to settings->network->adapter1 -> change to (bridged adapter)->click ok

Finally restart the ubuntu and check it will work

Comment: Can you please explain why this works?